# Combining time series to increase sensitivity

Tags: time-series, python, dataset, sensitivity-specificity

I have two sensors logging data synchronously. The two sensors are similar, so the recorded time series are correlated except for some special conditions.

I recorded data in different input parameter conditions of the system. And I would like to combine the two time series in one. The objective of this combination is to increase the sensitivity to system parameter changes.

How can I do it? Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If the two time series were recorded at the same moments of time (more or less) then [vector autoregressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression) (VAR) is one way of combining them. They allow you to model the two time series as a 2-dimensional process $(X_t, Y_t)$ and check if values $(X_{t-1}, Y_{t-1})$ are predictive of $X_t$ or $Y_t$.

Many tests have been developed for detecting structural changes and/or trends in VAR.